# How do I log out users from a restricted page if they are already logged in on another device?

Tags: plugins, content-restriction

Hope someone can help me. My client and I are down to the wire on this project and I can't seem to figure out a solution for this problem.

I'm currently using WP Bouncer to limit the amount of devices logged in to a user account to one device. I have the Groups plugin setup to restrict certain pages on the site as well.

The problem: The WP Bouncer plugin logs a user off on one device once another device logs in. However the user must go to another page in order to see that they were logged out. This creates a problem for my client. Once a user is on a restricted page on one device, he can login on another device and view the same restricted page, allowing both devices to view the page at once. Is there a way to check periodically if a user is logged in? I don't want to use any idle user plugins because the restricted pages include videos and digital magazines. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I think that the main problem of your client is not having a clue how the web works. Does he know about print screen and general print functions? or about proxies? Anyway this is either too broad or just off-topic here.

Comment: Agreed. Sometimes clients need feedback too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use AJAX to check if the user is logged in. You could use `setInterval` to check every 30 seconds (or whatever).

I tested the following code, and it works. First, create a file in your theme directory called **ajax.js** and put this code in it:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    var check_user_is_logged_in = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
            data: {action:'is_user_logged_in'},
            success:function(data) {
                if ( data == 'no' ) {
                    window.location.href = "http://mywebsite.com";
                }
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    };

    setInterval(function(){
        check_user_is_logged_in();
    }, 30000);
})( jQuery );
```

In the above code, change "mywebsite.com" to whatever URL you want to redirect logged out users to. You can also adjust `30000`. That's the number of milliseconds it should wait between checking.

Next, in your theme's `functions.php` file, add this code:

```
function na_check_user_logged_in() {
    // Simply check if the user is logged in or not and echo 'yes' or 'no'
    echo ( is_user_logged_in() ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    wp_die();
}

function na_enqueue_scripts(){
    // Enqueue our ajax.js script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'na_ajax_example', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/ajax.js', 'jquery');

    // Reveal the ajax_url for our script     
    wp_localize_script( 'na_ajax_example', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
};

add_action( 'wp_ajax_is_user_logged_in', 'na_check_user_logged_in' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_is_user_logged_in', 'na_check_user_logged_in' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'na_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Right now, this code will run on every page. You will need to edit the `na_enqueue_scripts` function and add some logic so it only enqueues the script on the protected pages.

Comment: You're very welcome!